# I need your help calculating my own indicator's profit in Tradingview pine editor

Tags: pine-script, pine-editor

Hi I'm new to pine editor so I need your help.

I made my own indicator, it gives long and short transactions, it works very well now But I want to find out how much profit is made at the end of each of these transactions and print it on the chart.

Let me give an example

My indicator gave a long transaction and this long transaction terminated because the bot placed a short position I want to see the profit made under the bar where this long position ends.

If there are those who can explain this code to me with an example, I am waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in variable `strategy.closedtrades.profit` which you can use for your example. You just pass it `strategy.closedtrades-1` as index (zero indexed) so you can get the profit of the last closed trade.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

smaFast = input.int(14)
smaSlow = input.int(28)

sma14 = ta.sma(close, smaFast)
sma28 = ta.sma(close, smaSlow)
plot(sma14, color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)
plot(sma28, linewidth=2)

longCondition = ta.crossover(sma14, sma28)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(sma14, sma28)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

var label _l = na
if (strategy.position_size[1] != strategy.position_size)
    profit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades-1)
    _l := label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(profit), yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

[image]

You can use the following algorithm to calculate your profit in percentage:

```
profitInPercent = 0.
for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades-1
    entryP = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(i)
    exitP = strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(i)
    profitInPercent += (exitP - entryP) / entryP * strategy.closedtrades.size(i)
avgProfitInPercent = strategy.closedtrades > 0 ? profitInPercent / strategy.closedtrades * 100 : na
```

Comment: So is there any way to show this as a percentage?. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: thank you senpai <3!